# KubernetesPodOperator on_failure_callback doesnt work on Airflow 2.4.2

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x, kubernetespodoperator

When using the newest Airflow version (2.4.2), the on_failure_callback doesnt get triggered on KubernetesPodOperator tasks. The on_success_callback works just fine.

For each KubernetesPodOperator task I set on_success_callback=send_success_notification() and on_failure_callback=send_failure_notification().

If the task succeeds, the notification gets send. However, in case of failure, the on_failure_callback doesn't get triggered. Is this some bug related to newest version?

Comment: To help you debug, can you post your complete log upon a DAG run which fails? It should normally show that the failure callback function was called. Can you post that along with your send_failure_notification() function? 

As an initial step to debug, can you log something at very beginning of your send_failure_notification function and see if you can see it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer but there's a mistake or typo in the examples:

> ... I set `on_success_callback=send_success_notification()` and `on_failure_callback=send_failure_notification()`.

Both the send_success_notification() and send_failure_notification() should be a reference to the function, not a function call. What I mean is you need to drop the brackets `()` from the end like:

`on_success_callback=send_success_notification` and `on_failure_callback=send_failure_notification`